# Is there a similar saying to "a drowning man will clutch at a straw" in French?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

It is about

> someone who is in a very difficult situation, and who will take any
> available opportunity to improve it

An example:

> Facing the possibility that his marriage might be over, John began
> visiting psychics to help him decide what to do. **A drowning man will
> clutch at a straw.**

I have checked on the internet but couldn't find one. Do you know any?

Comment: Hello. It'd better if you provide an example of usage of this idiom and what is its meaning.

Comment: i have added the meaning.

Comment: Could you please also provide an example of usage in, e.g., a possible dialogue? I.e. give some context. I'm sure that native speakers will find a French idiom conveying the meaning (not necessarily a one-to-one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No native speaker of French and English. According to: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_drowning_man_will_clutch_at_a_straw

> "a drowning man will clutch at a straw"

has an equivalent shorter version

> "grasp at straws".

According to https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/grasping+at+straws.html one gets some ways to convey the desired meaning in French (not necessarily the Metropolitan French) such as:

> It is total grasping at straws. On fait flèche de tout bois.

> Or are we clutching at straws here? Ou parlons-nous à tort et à travers ?

and so on.

According to https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/grasping+at+straws one may also use:

> **se raccrocher aux branches**

e.g.

> I mean, they must be really grasping at straws.    Ils doivent vraiment se raccrocher aux branches.

Cf.

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_raccrocher_aux_branches

https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/35991

**EDIT**

(Thanks to native speaker @Pas un clue).

> 'Se raccrocher aux branches'

is an option. In the exact contexte, one may use

> «on tente de se raccrocher à n'importe quelle branche»;

or

> «...à n'importe quoi»;

but it's not as colorful as the original English idiom. A couple of examples of usage in French: [1](https://books.google.ca/books?id=53fztNdn7kcC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=se%20raccrocher%20%C3%A0%20n%27importe%20quoi&source=bl&ots=Ct7Qu3jLT4&sig=ACfU3U1N6RPuk7C_i1DTQcMK7Gh9KxU18A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiztqDAnZTqAhXjRzABHTq1A-84ChDoATAAegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=se%20raccrocher%20%C3%A0%20n%27importe%20quoi&f=false); [2](https://books.google.ca/books?id=FqF_ag3ntHwC&pg=PA294&lpg=PA294&dq=se%20raccrocher%20%C3%A0%20n%27importe%20quoi&source=bl&ots=FwixtT2bDi&sig=ACfU3U2WKDJGiNnUbFxnPQ_mm9Ak4Bn4LQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii__yunZTqAhXtSzABHT0NCe8Q6AEwCHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=se%20raccrocher%20%C3%A0%20n%27importe%20quoi&f=false). A literal translation from English to French is provided [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=jh5SqZ6ibiAC&dq=on%20s%27accroche%20%C3%A0%20n%27importe%20quoi&pg=PA241&lpg=PA241&sig=ACfU3U2JfETyeT6ztQ42rwKRJz5F8Dogiw&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=on%20s%27accroche%20%C3%A0%20n%27importe%20quoi). The image may not be customary in French, but very understandable nonetheless.

**EDIT 2**

(Thanks to native speaker @Personne)

Another way to convey the same meaning:

> **Se donner au premier saint venu**.

Comment: Entendu, mais sans référence écrite dans *ngram* : « Se donner au premier saint venu »